# How to calculate sampling error for proportionate sampling?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, inference, descriptive-statistics, stratification

I have done sampling using Proportionate Stratified Random Sampling.

The table below shows the proportion of each groups in the sample and population.
[image]

This is the formula for Standard Error (Proportionate Stratified Random Sampling)

```
Standard Error = Z * √(p * (1 – p) / n)
```

​
Can someone please help me to calculate sampling error for various proportionate groups.

```
(p1 * (1 – p1) +/- (p2 * (1 – p2)) +/-..... / (n1+n2+...) (so is it + or  - )
```

or

```
sqrt( (p1(1-p1) + p2(1-p2) +p3(1-p3) +...... ) / N(total sample size)
```

Also if I can use some other metrics to see if the sample is a representative of population.

Answer (score 0):

I need a bit more data to help you with the sampling error, but just know its the same as standard deviation, but replace p with p^. That accounts for your standard error.

"**Also if I can use some other metrics to see if the sample is a representative of population.**"
Not much I know except for knowing a few conditions. Since we are using proportion, we have to have the following conditions be met.

1. The sampling method was from random sampling/SRS and unbiased.
2. p^n>10 q^n>10.
3. The sample size is less than 10% of the population size.

If all that checks out, you should have a pretty good representative of your population.

Hope that helped :)